# best way to extract all patterns of date from email string using regex or any other methods?

Tags: python, regex, date

So date can be of different formats like DD/MM/YYYY OR DD/MM OR DD-MM-YYYY OR DD-MM OR DD month or DDth month or month DDth . for these many cases at least i am trying to find an optimised way to extract it from an input string(email). Is there any method other than regular expression?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to bother with regex (which is obviously the best solution), you can still look at already implemented libraries like *datefinder* :

For example, this guy made the work for you to find any kind of date into texts:

https://github.com/akoumjian/datefinder

To install : 
    pip install datefinder

```
import datefinder

string_with_dates = "entries are due by January 4th, 2017 at 8:00pm
    created 01/15/2005 by ACME Inc. and associates."

matches = datefinder.find_dates(string_with_dates)

for match in matches:
    print match

# Output
2017-01-04 20:00:00
2005-01-15 00:00:00
```